# C# использование функции kernel32 CreateProcess

Tags: c#, winapi, процесс

Есть две программы, написанные на с#. Обе - консольные приложения, в каждой создается форма (`System.Windows.Forms.Form`).
Первая программа в процессе своей работы создает/уничтожает вторую программу. Вот код создания процесса второй программы:

```
var proc = new System.Diagnostics.Process
{
    StartInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo
    {
        FileName = exe,
        Arguments = args
    },
    EnableRaisingEvents = true
};
proc.Start();
```

Т.е. я имею консоль первой программы + окно первой программы + несколько таких же пар для каждого запущенного экземпляра второй программы.
Все работает, как надо. Но мне жутко надоело, что новые процессы постоянно перехватывают фокус на себя (при создании). Нашел [вот такое решение](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12586957/how-do-i-open-a-process-so-that-it-doesnt-have-focus) (ответ benrwb). Проверил - фокус больше не перехватывает. Программы запускаются, только вот

1. консоль теперь одна на все программы
2. при уничтожении созданной (второй) программы
   закрывается и основная программа

Я посмотрел описание функции `CreateProcess`, ее флагов. Попытался добавить флаги `DETACHED_PROCESS`, `CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE` и т.д. но методом тыка ничего путного не получилось.

Как из программы c# запускать абсолютно несвязанные процессы (как если бы я вручную запускал exe-файл) и при этом чтобы новые окна вообще не перехватывали фокус? (не надо предлагать возвращать перехваченный новым окном фокус обратно - это не подходит)

**UPD 1**

Вопрос такой: как из программы, написанной на c#, сделать запуск другой программы, написанной на c#, аналогично приведенному выше коду, но с помощью функции из kernel32.dll `CreateProcess`. У меня есть доступ к исходным кодам обоих программ.

**UPD 2**

Следующий код создает новый процесс, не перехватывая фокус, но с консолью родительского процесса. При закрытии созданного процесса закрывается и главный процесс. Если добавить флаги `CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE`, `DETACHED_PROCESS` или `CREATE_NEW_PROCESS_GROUP`, результат не меняется.

```
STARTUPINFO si = new STARTUPINFO();
si.cb = (UInt32)Marshal.SizeOf(si);
si.dwFlags = STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW;
si.wShowWindow = SW_SHOWNOACTIVATE;

UInt32 dwCreationFlags = ABOVE_NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS;

PROCESS_INFORMATION pi = new PROCESS_INFORMATION();

CreateProcess(name, path + " " + inprms, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero, false, dwCreationFlags, IntPtr.Zero, System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(path), ref si, out pi);
```

**UPD 3**

Нашел такое "решение" средствами c#:

```
// основная программа - запуск дочерней программы
var proc = new System.Diagnostics.Process
{
    StartInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo
    {
        FileName = exe,
        Arguments = args,
        UseShellExecute = false,
        WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden
    },
    EnableRaisingEvents = true
};
proc.Start(); 

// дочерняя программа - событие загрузки главного окна
Load += (s, e) =>
{
    Show();
};
```

При таком подходе у дочерних программ нет консоли, весь вывод направляется в консоль главного процесса. Закрытие любого из процессов никак не влияет на другие процессы. Не знаю, почему, но `Show()` не перехватывает фокус (как мне и нужно). 
Если написать `UseShellExecute = true`, то консоль так же будет одна, но `Show()` будет перехватывать фокус на дочернее окно. Если кто-нибудь мне объяснит, почему, буду признателен.

**UPD 4**

Так же хотелось бы узнать, как же все-таки это можно сделать через `CreateProcess()`.

**UPD 5**

После некоторого времени отладки оказалось, что описанный выше пример работает непредсказуемо (то фокусит, то нет). Испробовав разные способы я нашел таки вариант, который меня устроил:

```
// основная программа - запуск дочерней программы
var proc = new System.Diagnostics.Process
{
    StartInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo
    {
        FileName = exe,
        Arguments = args,
        WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden
    },
    EnableRaisingEvents = true
};
proc.Start(); 

// дочерняя программа - при создании главного окна
using (Window = new MyWindow())
{
    Window.Show();
    Window.SendToBack();

    ConsoleVisible(WINDOW_STYLE.SW_SHOWMINNOACTIVE);

    Application.Run(Window);
} 

public static void ConsoleVisible(UInt16 WINDOW_STYLE)
{
    var handle = GetConsoleWindow();
    ShowWindow(handle, WINDOW_STYLE);
}

[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
static extern IntPtr GetConsoleWindow();
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
static extern bool ShowWindow(IntPtr hWnd, UInt16 nCmdShow);
```

Запуск процесса с `WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden` скрывает как само окно приложения, так и его консоль. В запускаемом приложении `Show()` восстанавливает окно формы, но! не фокусит его, а только размещает поверх всех окон. С помощью `SendToBack()` оно отправляется на задний план, фокус все это время не тронут. Консоль в это время спрятана и нигде не отображается. Чтобы ее вернуть, вызываем WinApi с флагом `SW_SHOWMINNOACTIVE`. Консоль появляется на панели задач в свернутом состоянии. Интересно то, что если использовать флаг `SW_SHOWNOACTIVATE`, то консоль восстанавливается и автоматически фокусится, что мне не подходит.

Благодарю всех, кто помогал.

Comment: Попробуйте, для начала, ShellExecute с параметром SW_SHOWNOACTIVATE.

Comment: Если я правильно понял, то такой вариант я добавил в UPD2. Или вы имели ввиду функцию WinApi?

Comment: UPD2 использует CreateProcess. Это может и неплохая идея, но эта функция слишком сложная. Думаю для вашей задачи больше подходит функция [ShellExecute](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/shell32/ShellExecute.html?diff=y)

Comment: @VadimTagil благодарю за подсказку. Пока нашел почти удовлетворяющий вариант. Когда буду причесывать код, обязательно опробую `ShellExecute`

Comment: Скорее всего, работает непредстказуемо из-за смешивания консольного приложения с Win Forms. Поведение таких приложений не изучено.

Answer (score 1):

По той же ссылке, что вы кинули есть более лаконичное решение:

```
public class MyClass
{
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern bool SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hWnd);

    public void doProcess(string filename, string arguments){

        using (Process proc = new Process())
        {
            proc.StartInfo.FileName = filename;
            proc.StartInfo.Arguments = arguments;
            proc.Start();

            SetForegroundWindow(proc.MainWindowHandle);
        }
    }
}
```

Новые процессы просто переносим на задний план.

Если у вас есть доступ к коду приложений, которые вы запускаете, то можете их доработать.

Например, что бы можно было передавать какие-то аргументы и при запуске само приложение уходило на задний план или сворачивалось.

А еще, вроде, можно запускать программу в свернутом состоянии через CMD:

```
start /min "" "C:\Windows\notepad.exe"
```

Comment: Я же написал, что вариант с возвратом фокуса не подходит.

Comment: Если я, например, пишу что-то в том же самом нотпаде и происходит создание окна с вашим кодом `SetForegroundWindow(proc.MainWindowHandle);`, то нотпад теряет фокус, а это мне не подходит. Копать надо именно в сторону использования `CreateProcess`, надеюсь, что найдутся люди, разбирающиеся в WinApi.

Comment: Вариант с запуском проги в свернутом режиме тоже не подходит

Comment: @user3424037, я думаю, что вам стоит добавить мотивы по которым вы хотите это делать в вопрос(Например, пример с нотпадом). Ранее не совсем был понятен смысл.

Comment: Вопрос поставлен четко. Запуск с помощью `CreateProcess` нового, независимого от запускающей программы, процесса. Мотивы тут не нужны.